# Someone Help Me To Print This Array Using Css Or In Tables

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, html-table

Can someone please help me to print this data using tables or css or bootstrap..?

**PHP Code Used:**

```
$url = "http://some-website.com/api/message";
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$count=count($json);
print_r ($json);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12491055
                    [device_id] => 18398
                    [message] => hi there!
                    [status] => received
                    [send_at] => 0
                    [queued_at] => 0
                    [sent_at] => 0
                    [delivered_at] => 0
                    [expires_at] => 0
                    [canceled_at] => 0
                    [failed_at] => 0
                    [received_at] => 1456228673
                    [error] => N/A
                    [created_at] => 1456271873
                    [contact] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3077686
                            [name] => charan
                            [number] => 123456789
                        )

                )
         )
)
```

I'm new in this php field so don't try to make your answers bit difficult one for me to understand or execute.

i want it to be printed like:

**Name:** some one

**Message:** Hi

Etc.........

just like online desposal mobile numbers & message's services sites

**Thanks In Advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at the array you already have, and drill down.

```
echo "Name: " . $json['result'][0]['contact']['name'];
```

Or:

```
echo "Message: " . $json['result'][0]['message'];
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro. I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

use `foreach()` to print your array.example:

```
   $tab=array('name'=>'Jack','last name'=>'sparrow');
    foreach($tab as $key=>$elem)
    {
       echo "$key : $elem <br>";
    }
//the result 
//name: jack
//last name : sparrow
```